# How to search a column that I added in Laravel Yajra Datatables with a relationship?

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

So i am using Yajra Datatables to make my datatable.

I have added a additional column like below so it can show the users name from a relationship.

```
->addColumn('customer_name', function (Order $order){
                return $order->user->name;
            })
```

Although this column appears in the datatable I am unable to search it. Below is the full function code:

```
public function viewDTPending(){
        $store= Auth::user()->store;
        $pending = Order::where('store', $store)->where('status', 'Pending')->orderBy('user_id')->groupBy('order_id', 'status', 'order_branch', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
        return Datatables::of($pending)
            ->addColumn('customer_name', function (Order $order){
                return $order->user->name;
            })
            ->editColumn('created_at', function (Order $order){
                    return $order->created_at->diffForHumans();
                })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

And below is the ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ url('getPendingOrdersDT') }}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'order_id', name: 'order_id' },
                { data: 'user_id', name: 'user_id' },
                { data: 'customer_name', name: 'customer_name' },
                { data: 'status', name: 'status' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

How could i get it to search the customer_name column?

Comment: `Order` model has a belongTo relation with `User` model?

Comment: @sta yes, because the data even shows. Its just that i cant filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Eager loading :

```
$pending = Order::with('user:id,name')->where('store', $store)->where('status', 'Pending')->orderBy('user_id')->groupBy('order_id', 'status', 'order_branch', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
   return Datatables::of($pending)
     ->addColumn('customer_name', function ($row){
          return $row->user['name'];
   })
```

Comment: hmm that doesnt work either. just get a bunch of errors when filtering.

Comment: Hi, so what you showed did kind of did work. The only thing missing was me not accessing it correctly in the ajax. In the ajax i had to do `{ data: 'user.name', name: 'user.name' },` You may want to edit this to the answer for people in the future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I hope I make the right edit? if so then you can access with `{ data: 'customer_name', name: 'customer_name' },`

Comment: You can delete this `addColumn` if you want, without it you can access through `{ data: 'user.name', name: 'user.name' }` , because you have eager load data `with('user:id,name')`

Comment: Yes i deleted the addColumn because i retreived it through the eager loading `user.name`. This is the correct way, and the fix for me,

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the name of the table along with the column.

**Example : name: 'users.id'**

We use this method to search ajax in the same system

or simple code :

```
    $objects = Model::query()
        ->leftJoin('curs', 'cur.id', '=', 'model.cur_id')
        ->select([
            'models.id',
            'models.address',
            'models.tag',
            'curs.title_en',
        ]);

    return Datatables::of($objects)
        ->addColumn('actions', function ($model) {
            return 'action'
        })
        ->make(true);
```

Comment: I tried that already, as well as `users.name` however i get an error: `DataTables warning: table id=table - Exception Message:` with the SQL query

Comment: DB::table('firstData')->rightJoin('joinTableName','firstData.id','=','joinTableName.firstDataId')

Use the example above to see if you have an error